# python printing string instead of printing the value

Tags: python, concatenation

I am trying to print the value of preset1 not the word preset1 and I can't make it do that.

```
print 'value%d' %(y)
```

this is printing:

```
value1
```

I have defined the value1 earlier which i was hoping to acquire.

```
value1 = decoded['options'][0] # this is in unicode
```

Comment: Don't use 'dynamic variables'. Use a dictionary or list instead (`values = {'value1': decoded['options'][0]}`, then `print values['value{}'.format(y)]`, for example).

Comment: Yes, I guess I have to just do that.  I ended up just using list.  thanks.